# Не работает отладка flask (debug)

Tags: python, flask, отладка, pycharm

Запускаю код в отладке:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

но отладка не работает, выкидывая ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем, если запустить под отладкой подобный код:

```
def plus(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(plus(3, 4))
```

то работает нормально.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, в чем причина ошибки работы отладки?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что при запуске под отладчиком падает при передаче `__name__`, когда оно равно `'__main__'`, т.е. когда модуль не импортирован, а запущен.

Скорее всего падение связано с тем, что при отладке скрипт запускается не напрямую, а через хелпер отладчика. У меня в консоли PyCharm при запуске пишет вот такое:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /snap/pycharm-professional/252/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 33461 --file /home/user/Projects/testflaskdebug/test.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.4746.96)
```

При запуске без отладчика:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/user/Projects/testflaskdebug/test.py
```

Варианты решения:

1. Если используете PyCharm Professional, то запускать с помощью конфигурации "Flask Server", а не просто "Python"
2. Первый параметр класса `Flask` называется `import_name` (т.е. импортируемое имя), как вариант можно передавать имя текущего модуля из глобальной переменной `__file__`, например так:

   ```
   from pathlib import Path
   from flask import Flask

   # Если имя файла модуля test.py, то будет передано 'test'
   app = Flask(Path(__file__).stem)
   ...
   ```
3. Передать вообще любую строку кроме `'__main__'`, и чтобы она не была похожа на имя файла, например со строкой `app = Flask("sdfsdf sdf")` запустится нормально, а `app = Flask("sdfsdf.sdf")` упадет с ошибкой. Но в целом надежнее использовать предыдущий вариант.

---

Вариант, который не сработал:

При запуске через конфигурацию "Flask Server" PyCharm Professional выводит в консоль следующее:

```
FLASK_APP = test.py
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 0
In folder /home/user/Projects/testflaskdebug
```

Т.е. заполняются некоторые переменные окружения и указывается текущая директория.

Пробовал добавлять те же переменные окружения в конфигурации запуска (поле Environment variables), указывать рабочую директорию (поле "Working directory"), но это не помогло, при запуске под отладчиком падает с тем же исключением.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 1):

Третий вариант сработал, спасибо. Не понятно только, в чем все же причина.

Вариант 4.
Если создать файл app.py и уже из него запускать приложение/дебаг, то все работает 'ok':

```
app.py
------
from main import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()




main.py
-------
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi'
```

Comment: Ну, тоже вариант. В этом случае в модуле main.py переменная `__name__` будет равна `main`, и все будет работать нормально. "Третий вариант сработал, спасибо." - вот как раз третий вариант я бы не советовал использовать, лучше использовать второй.